# DNS - IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, monitoring

I have AD/DNS running on a Win2003 Server, and I'm using Spiceworks. When I run a scan with SpiceWorks I get a lot of DNS errors. Mainly "IP Address does not resolve to a hostname". And if I look at DNS all those IP errors below do not have corresponding A Records. I have close to 60 "IP Address does not resolve to a hostname" errors on the network, and I am wondering why DNS isn't doing what it is suppose to be doing. Some are static and some are not, most are on a domain but a few are not. Most have XP but a couple are win98 or win7 clients. Most of them get rebooted every day.

I had problems with some PTRs not getting updated or non existent in the reverse lookup, and I fixed those. I do not have much experience with DNS, so this might be something easy :) hopefully... but I also do not want to make things worse. Any help would be appreciated.

```
192.168.180.144 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.144
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.145 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.145
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.146 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.146
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.151 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.151
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.157 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.157
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.165 → does not resolve → brn_8e21a8
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.172 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.172
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname

192.168.180.179 → does not resolve → 192.168.180.179
IP Address does not resolve to a hostname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have a grasp on, the issue is with your rDNS zone and the PTR records within it.

That being said, rDNS zones and PTR records are not required for the proper operation of AD or AD DNS. Unless you have specific needs or requirements that there be a functioning rDSN zone I would ignore these Spiceworks messages. Your AD, DNS, and all clients (workstations and servers) will all function perfectly happily without a rDNS zone.

Comment: Just as a note, it's also pretty easy to get clients to register themselves in the directory and DNS thereby creating any required rDNS entries.  Via GPO: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294785/ Via DHCP: Flip the option for "register PTR records". But like @joeqwerty mentioned its certainly not required.